# Two websites, two domains (ccTLD), two markets but same content - SEO Impact?

Tags: seo, domains, google-search, multiple-domains

We have an ecommerce website registered as *example*.ie (Ireland) with high traffic. We want to expand to the UK (.co.uk).

The website content will be identical except a change in pricing (EUR -> GBP) and contact address / phone number (both UK based).

We currently have number 1 rank or first page for all key search terms on Google.ie but rank nowhere near first page at all on Google.co.uk. This is the main drivers for a dedicated website. Along with a presumption UK shoppers prefer to buy (our competitive products) from a .co.uk than a .ie (our products will ship also from a UK address).

\What is the safest way to enter the new market without impact on SEO in the current market (if any)?

We don't mind if the current *example*.ie site is impacted on Google.co.uk results as it doesn't rank well but as long as it doesn't impact our Google.ie results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you need to do is implement `hreflang tags` to both websites - they are a special type of canonical command that will tell Google that there is a **localized version of the same content** and Google should use them accordingly. When implemented correctly, this will guarantee that your websites won't compete with each other within Google, all while providing the correct/best user experience.

HREFLANG can get very complicated very fast, so I would start with [this guide from Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) and if you need more information, [this guide from Ahrefs](https://ahrefs.com/blog/hreflang-tags/) is a great starting point, too.